# Unable to access reactive objects inside function used to generate dynamic shiny content

Tags: r, shiny

## Background

I am having an issue accessing reactive content when creating dynamic content for a `shiny` app. Specifically, I have a function (`mk_obj` in the sample code below) that creates a list of functions used to generate `shiny` objects (both UI and input/output elements in the server function). However, the functions contained within the `mk_obj` function are unable to reference reactive objects instantiated within the `server()` function, even when lazily invoked from within that function as a member of the `output` object (the errors noted below are thrown when a user clicks on the download button).

## Specific Question

How can I access `r_data` from within `downloadHandler()` below to arrive at the expected result and in a manner that I can generalize to other output functions (e.g. `DT::renderDataTable()`, `renderPlot()`, etc.) ?

## Code

The following code block contains a working example of the issue at hand, along with three alternative assignments to `xdata` attempted (generally, appears that the `downloadHandler()` function cannot locate the environment in which the `r_data` object appears). I have encountered the issue with several `output` rendering objects, not just the `downloadHandler()` function:

```
# Libraries
library(tidyverse);
library(shiny);
library(shinydashboard);

# Data
srcdata <- tibble::as_tibble(list(a=1:100,b=101:200,c=201:300));

# Functions -- R Worker
mk_obj <- function() {
  attr <- list(items=c('a'));
  list(
    server_output=list(
      dl_data=function() {
        x <- lapply(attr$items, function(x) {
          downloadHandler(
            filename = function() { paste('file.csv') },
            content  = function(con) {
              xdata <- r_data(); # <<< Error: "Error in r_data: could not find function "r_data""
#             xdata <- match.fun('r_data')(); # <<< Error: "Error in get: object 'r_data' of mode 'function' was not found"
#             xdata <- eval(parse(text='r_data'))(); # <<< Error: "Error in eval: object 'r_data' not found"
              write.csv(xdata, con);
            },
            contentType='text/csv'
          );
        })
        names(x) <- sprintf('dl_%s',tolower(attr$items));
        return(x);
      }
    ),
    ui_tabitems= lapply(attr$items, function(x) {
      tabItem(tabName=sprintf('tab%s',tolower(x)), downloadButton(outputId=sprintf('dl_%s',tolower(x)), label='Download'))
    })
  );
};

# Dynamic shiny objects
dynamic_content <- list(obj1=mk_obj());

# Server
server <- function(input, session, output) {
  r_data <- reactive({srcdata[c(input$row_select),]})
  output$srcdata_out <- renderDataTable({r_data()});
  # dynamic_content <- list(obj1=mk_obj()); # <-- Have attempted invocation here, instead of outside the server() function, with same effect (as expected)
  invisible(lapply(c(dynamic_content$obj1$server_output),
                  function(x) {
                xouts <- x();
                for (i in paste0(names(xouts))) {
                      output[[i]] <<- xouts[[i]];
                };
              }));
}

# UI
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "POC"),
  dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(id = "tabs",
      menuItem("Menu1",  tabName = "taba"),
      menuItem("Menun",  tabName = "tabn", selected=TRUE)
      )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    do.call('tabItems',append(list(
      tabItem(tabName="tabn", fluidRow(sliderInput( inputId='row_select', label='rowID', min=1, max=NROW(srcdata), value=10)),
                          hr(),
                          fluidRow(dataTableOutput('srcdata_out')))),
      dynamic_content$obj1$ui_tabitems)))
);

# App
shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server);
```

## Expected Output

For this example, the `shiny` app should offer a `CSV` file to download the selected row of data, using the slider. Instead, the errors noted in the code comments thrown.

## Other Thoughts

While there are straightforward implementations of `renderUI()` with repetitive object declarations, I am attempting to automatically generate `shiny` content that may *not* appear in a contiguous section and would like to avoid repetitively declaring IDs manually. Additionally, I am trying to keep templates data-centric (as opposed to presentation-centric) such that I can use pieces of the auto-generated `shiny` objects through an application that may vary by presentation layout/ container.

Appreciate the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to use a `reactive` within a function, without passing it as an argument.

My suggestion is to use [Shiny modules](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html), they were developed for this particular purpose.

#### How it works:

You can pass **reactives** to modules quite easily:

1. Write a module: `mk_obj <- function(input, output, session, df) {...}`

The `reactive` will be passed to the `df` argument.

2. Use the reactive within the module: `df()`
3. Call the module within Server using a unique id (`"example"`): `callModule(module = mk_obj, id = "example", df = r_data)`

I completely rewrote your code as it's really hard to read and understand.

#### Code:

```
# Libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

# Data
srcdata <- tibble::as_tibble(list(a=1:100,b=101:200,c=201:300))

# Functions -- R Worker

## UI part of the module
mk_obj_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  downloadButton(ns("download_btn"), label = "Download")
}

# Server part of the module reactive will be passed to the df argument
mk_obj <- function(input, output, session, df) {
  output$download_btn <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "file.csv",
    content  = function(file) {
      write.csv(df(), file, row.names = FALSE)
    },
    contentType='text/csv'
  )
}

# Server
server <- function(input, session, output) {
  r_data <- reactive( {
    srcdata[c(input$row_select), ]
  })
  output$srcdata_out <- renderDataTable( {
    r_data()
  })

  # Call the module with the id: example. Pass the reactive r_data as df.
  ## Note that brackets should not be used when passing a reactive to the module!
  callModule(module = mk_obj, id = "example", df = r_data)
}

# UI
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "POC"),
  dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(id = "tabs",
                               menuItem("Menu1",  tabName = "taba"),
                               menuItem("Menun",  tabName = "tabn", selected=TRUE)
  )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "taba",
              mk_obj_ui("example")
      ),
      tabItem(tabName="tabn", 
              sliderInput(inputId='row_select', label='rowID', min=1, max=NROW(srcdata), value=10),
              hr(),
              dataTableOutput('srcdata_out')
      ) 
    )
  )
)

# App
shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

PS.: Drop the semicolons as they are obsolete in R.